Mafiosi abduct man from Italian village for job in America. What's the film?
They pick up a man in the "old country", fly him to America (NY?), and use him as executioner in a gangland murder. Then they fly him back to his Italian vilage.

Can you add a bit more details like when did you watched it? Is it a made for television or theater released film.

There's an Italian movie of the 60s or maybe even the late 50s (it's in b/w) where the story revolves around such a scheme.
Except that the main character lives in Milano where he works as a middle manager in some big factory. The abduction, his shipping (in a wooden box aboard a cargo plane!) to NYC, his killing some mafia boss in a barber shop and his return happen in a less then 24 hours span while he was summer vacationing in Sicily with his family at some relatives house.
In order to cover his trip abroad from his family, the Sicilian relatives organize a fake hunting from dawn to sunset.
Funny that I remember all these details, but I can recall neither the movie title, nor the name of the actor playing the main character which I'm sure was one of the leading Italian movie stars of the time.

Ok, I made some research and found the movie!
The movie title is "Mafioso", starring Alberto Sordi and with the direction of Alberto Lattuada. It came out in 1962 in Italy, but was distributed only two years later in the U.S.
Here's the Wiki page of the movie. Those who can read Italian may switch to the somewhat more detailed Italian version.

The Sopranos have an episode like this. The abduction element doesn't fit though.
Tony has two cousins flown over to do a hit on Rusty Millio. They kill Rusty in his driveway and fly straight back

I bet the Sopranos episode was inspired by the movie I have in mind. This movie must be from the eighties or even seventies...
